# One-liner for generating natural language looking words

Tags: python, string, random

When teaching computing science, I sometimes need to create arbitrary samples of data for demonstrating various algorithms, for instance sorting algorithms.

I would like to get an easy way of generating lists of `(random word, random value)`. If I need ~10 such tuples, I can hardcode `(names, value)` tuples. But if I need ~50 such tuples, I can't do that.

I tried using *ad-hoc* function generating alternate vowel and consonant string, but I noticed that many students would focus on this function rather than on the main algorithm, asking what is the purpose of such or such line of code, and spending most of the time on that *ad-hoc* function.

I don't encounter such an issue when importing some function because the module is like a black box for them.

Thus I wonder if you could figure out some module in standard Anaconda distributions (students should not have to install anything more) that could lead to an easy to type one-liner such as

```
from XXX import YYY
from random import random, randrange
L = [ ( YYY(random()), randrange(0, 100)) for _ in range(50) ]
```

where `YYY(random())` or any other syntax would result in some more or less natural language sounding string.

I don't ask for existing words, since I usually claim they are some names of people, but I would rather get `tabati` than `xwyaer`. Of course, if you are aware of some hidden gem in `scipy` containing hardcoded names of towns or whatever, it would be great.

Any idea?

Comment: Have a look at [Faker](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/). It has a pretty solid engine for generating realistic random data

Answer (score 4):

You should look at [`Faker`](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/) (`pip install Faker` or similar for anaconda). It has lots functions to generate fake (real looking or truly random) data:

```
from faker import Faker

f = Faker("en_US")

f.word() 
# random word from set locale

f.words(10) 
# list of ten random (but real) words

f.city()
f.first_name()
f.last_name()
# ...
```